# Azure Websites and Mailboxes

Tags: email, azure

I'm trying to understand Azure and I really like the way everything is implemented. I have a number of websites hosted with Heart Internet. Using Azure Websites would definitely save me money on reseller hosting fees. Plus Heart's UI is dreadful. However, what do I do with email? I can set up mail accounts on each domain at present, but there is no way of doing this with Azure Websites. Well no that I can see.

The only way I can see of doing it is to 'spin up' a VM and install a mail server.

Sendgrid doesn't seem to be an option as it appears to be a bulk mail service (unless I've got the wrong end of the stick).

Most of my websites don't need email, but the exceptions stop me from moving.

What's the best way to get around this 'cos I'd really like to use Azure?

Comment: This is more of a serverfault than a stackoverflow questions as it concerns operations and not programming. I suspect that offerings like office365 will fit your needs as you seem to be in the Microsoft ecosystem. But basically any email provider (e.g. gmail) could probably offer what you are looking for.

Comment: Cheers Simon. when you click Azure Support it has a big link suggesting questions can be asked on Stackoverflow! O365 charge per mail account which will cost too much and I want to be able set up email@domain.co.uk not email@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

Your website and your mail do not need to be hosted on the same server or even by the same vendor. You can update your domain's DNS records to include custom `MX` records to route mail to hosted email providers.

A few hosted email options that include support for custom domain names are:

- [Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Verify-your-domain-in-Office-365-6383f56d-3d09-4dcb-9b41-b5f5a5efd611)
- [Google Apps for Work](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295)
- or even continuing to use [Heart Internet](https://www.heartinternet.uk/email-hosting/personal-email-hosting) for email hosting.

If you do choose to setup a VM for a mail server, you would still modify the domain's DNS records to point to this VM for mail routing and your Azure web site for most other requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that VM is the only way to go. My suggestion would be to go with a hosting control panel such as [Plesk](http://www.plesk.com/) for windows or [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.com/) for Linux. They have the mail server built right in.

Answer (score 0):

Totally OT, but I would use Amazon's SES to send email.  They provide an SMTP interface and you can send email from whatever domain you want, as long as you validate that domain with them.  Their prices are dirt cheap.